# Room Database overriding inserted objects

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

I have my entity object this way:

```
@Entity(tableName = "woks", foreignKeys = arrayOf(ForeignKey(
    entity = Order::class,
    parentColumns = arrayOf("entryid"),
    childColumns = arrayOf("order_id"),
    onDelete = ForeignKey.CASCADE
)))
data class Wok(
    val order_id: String
) {
    @ColumnInfo(name = "id")
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    var id: Long = 0
}
```

and the insertion in my DAO file defined this way:

```
@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
abstract fun insertWok(wok: Wok): Long
```

As you can see the conflict is ignored so when ever I tried to insert the same object again it will override that object and keep increment the id.

So what I want to achieve is inserting the same object so many times

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you want to duplicate rows in the table?

Comment: @Oussaki: remove (onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE). Then each time you insert that object it will create a new row with a new id in the database.

Comment: @WilliMentzel i've tried that but the same result

Comment: @Oussaki pls show your insertWok calls

Answer (score 1):

To insert your object many times, you need to change the primary key. 
Room is based  on it to know if  it's a new object or not.

Comment: But the primary key is an incremented value !

Comment: I saw that. But if you query the db to get a wok, then try to insert it, it doesn't work because both objects have the same id. So you need to "clear" the id for this new object, or make a clone of the object coming from the DB (without the id) to let room generate a new id.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried many combination which are possible with your given information, but i didn't came with anything as you are saying.

Can u please share more information like your contructor, how you are creating work object,
actually what happen with output (before-after)

This may be happen, 
  if your work object id is 0 while passing to your insertWork method
if u put 2 identical object with id 0 of both, because of autogenrate=true room will autogenrate id for them, and as room will create unique id, these object treat as different object.

Comment: @Andrzej Ziółek  ....have you read my full answer? In 2nd part i have explain what could be the issue. so stop replying in such a way.I have done some test on this scenario after that i put my answer. If you got answer why not you  answer it. If not .. off.